# error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char

Tags: java

Mi problema es que cuando ejecuto este código:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(CodelandUsernameValidation(s.nextLine())); 
}
```

Y en el input pongo algún carácter que no sea alfabético o numérico, me aparece este error:

```
Main.java:17: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char letra = str.substring(i,i+1);
```

La clase CodelandUsernameValidation tiene este codigo:

```
public static String CodelandUsernameValidation(String str) {
// code goes here 
int num = str.length();
Boolean comprobar;
if(num >= 4 && num <= 25){
  char letra = str.charAt(0);
  comprobar = Character.isAlphabetic(letra);

  if(comprobar == true){
    if(str.substring(num - 1,num) != "_"){
      for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        letra = str.substring(i,i+1);
        if(str.substring(i, i + 1) != "_"){
          if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(letra)) {            
            str = "true";
          } else if(str.substring(i, i + 1) != "_"){
            str = "false";
          }       
        }
      }  
    }  
  } else {
    str = "false";

  }

} else {
  str = "false";
}

return str;
```

}

Me podrian ayudar a solucionarlo?, no manejo mucho la variable char y no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre ella

Comment: char no es una variable, es un tipo. Y el problema es que `subString` devuelve un `String` y `char` no puede ser `char` y `String` a la vez. Vamos, que tienes que declarar `letra` como `String` o hacer `char letra = str.substring(i,i+1).charAt(0)`, esto último solo si estás seguro de que siempre habrá una única letra, que es lo que viene siendo un `char` :)

Comment: Fuera a parte, yo inicializaría la variable boolean comprobar como true, y únicamente cambiaría su valor a false, sino, es redundante comprobar algo para cambiarlo a true.

Comment: se me olvido agradecerles, los dos me ayudaron a corregir y entender mejor el tema, gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error indica el problema

```
Main.java:17: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char letra = str.substring(i,i+1);
```

Estas tratando de asignar una cadena a la variable `letra` que es de tipo `char`, esto no es posible, ya que una cadena es una secuencia de caracteres y la variable de tipo `char` solo puede almacenar un solo carácter.

En este caso, en lugar de usar el metodo [`substring()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) usa [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) para que puedas obtener un solo caracter:

```
  ...
  ...
  if(comprobar == true){
    //if(str.substring(num - 1,num) != "_"){
    if (str.charAt(num - 1) != '_') {
      for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //letra = str.substring(i,i+1);
        letra = str.charAt(i);
        //if(str.substring(i, i + 1) != "_"){
        if (str.charAt(i) != '_') {
          if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(letra)) {            
            str = "true";
          } else {
            str = "false";
          }       
        }
      }  
    } 
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

### Acerca del error: "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char"

Tipo "String", su valor puede ser vacio, puede ser un solo caracter o puede ser una cadena de caracteres.
Ejemplo:

```
String myOneString = "";
String myTwoString = "a";
String myThreeString = "abc";
```

Tipo 'char', su valor únicamente puede ser un solo caracter.
Ejemplo:

```
char myCharacter = 'a';
```

La diferencia al asignar el valor está en que al asignar tipo "String" usamos comillas dobles, al asignar tipo 'char' usamos comillas sencillas.

Comment: -1 No solo porque la explicación sobre los tipos de datos es incompleta, por ejemplo de Char obvias su principal característica que es que siempre es uno y solo un caracter, no más, ni menos, mientras que string es una cadena de caracteres, que puede tener cero, uno o varios caracteres. Por otro lado, el ejemplo de código que das no tiene nada que ver con el código publicado por el AP en la pregunta, con lo cuál dudo que ayude a resolver su problema.

Comment: Ese no es exactamente el problema. En la línea del error no está intentado asignar un literal. No se dio cuenta que `substring` devuelve un `String` en lugar de un `char`.